# How to define the normalized spacing?

Tags: functions

I want to write the formula for normalized spacing in Mathematica and I want to use it in rest of the problem. To write the formula $D=(n-i+1)(x_{(i)}-x_{(i-1)})$ I wrote the following function.

`D[x[i]] = (n - i + 1)*(x[i] - x[i - 1])`

To check its correctness I found its sum which should be $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ but I got $\sum_{i=1}^nx[i]$. Can anyone help me to define D correctly?

Comment: By the way, `D` has a meaning of derivative in MA. You may use `d` for your function. You can define it as `d[x_,i_,n_]:=(n - i + 1)*(x[i] - x[i - 1])`

Comment: please show a complete MWE including all the code you used to run it. Also, that is not a function. That is not how functions are defined in Mathematica. And better not use `D` for a name of your function.

Comment: The following is my code and I need answer for e as  $e=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. But I didn't get it.    
       ```b[x_, n_, i_] := (n - i + 1)*(x[i] - x[i - 1])```                                                                  
  ```e = \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]\(b[x, n, i_]\)\)```